# How to make Jetty return 503 during a high cpu usage?

Tags: configuration, jetty

How to config Jetty so that it can receive only the first several hundred requests and return 5xx to the timeout requests.

I performed as https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/High_Load#Thread_Pool

here is my jetty config

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

<New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
            <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/<SystemProperty name="jetty.appkey" default="jetty"/>.log.yyyy_mm_dd</Arg>
            <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg>
            <Arg type="int">10</Arg>
            <Arg><Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone"><Arg>GMT+8</Arg></Call></Arg>
            <Arg type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</Arg>
            <Arg type="string"></Arg>
            <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
<Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="info"><Arg>Redirecting stderr/stdout to <Ref id="ServerLogName"/></Arg></Call>
<Call class="java.lang.System" name="setErr"><Arg><Ref id="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>
<Call class="java.lang.System" name="setOut"><Arg><Ref id="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>

<Set name="ThreadPool">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
        <!-- specify a bounded queue -->
        <Arg>
            <New class="java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue">
                <Arg type="int">300</Arg>
            </New>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="minThreads">20</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
    </New>
</Set>

<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host"/></Set>
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
            <Set name="acceptQueueSize">100</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">100</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <!-- Set name="confidentialPort">8063</Set -->
            <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">100</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">100</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

then i take a ab stress test

```
ab -c 10000 -n 20000 -l
```

but the result is

```
Concurrency Level:      10000
Time taken for tests:   98.700 seconds
Complete requests:      20000
Failed requests:        16909
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 16909, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      1
Total transferred:      301105691 bytes
HTML transferred:       296709079 bytes
Requests per second:    202.63 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       49349.994 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       4.935 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2979.22 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        2  314 301.8    355    1149
Processing:   313 40984 33341.1  36948   98109
Waiting:        0 40112 33522.7  35817   98107
Total:        720 41298 33360.0  37063   98615

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  37063
  66%  59864
  75%  71831
  80%  78646
  90%  91082
  95%  95328
  98%  97180
  99%  97705
 100%  98615 (longest request)
```

I use '-l' option and there are still a lot of Failed requests, so I retried at the same time I open another tab and curl the url, not return 503 but the correct response after a long while.

Is there anywhere wrong in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

[Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) consider upgrading.

Also, when you do, you might want to look into the techniques for the Jetty 9.x [LowResourceMonitor](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/limit-load.html) (detect behavior at connector level) or [DosFilter](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/DoSFilter.html) (detect behavior at specific url-pattern level) and setup a custom solution for your own detection of low resources and/or load to then respond with a 503 status code.

Also, upper bound limiting ThreadPools are never a good idea for dealing with load concerns.  Its like attempting to control traffic on a highway by limiting the number of on-ramps the highway has, it just creates a huge backlog wanting to get on the highway.

Comment: Appreciate for your answer, I read the LowResourceMonitor and find that is exactly what I want. But due to some reason my server is still using jetty 8, I tried to set 'maxIdleTime', 'lowResourcesConnections' and 'lowResourcesMaxIdleTime' in SelectChannelConnector but why they do nothing in high stress?